# Prove that $ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x =\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

In a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947870/integrating-displaystyle-int-0-pi-2-sin2x-over-1-sin-x-cos-xdx) the following integral was evaluated
$$ 
      \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x
     =\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}x/2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} 
     =\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{\mathrm{d}x/2}{2 + \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x
     =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x/2}{1+x+x^2}
$$
I noticed something interesting, namely that
$$ 
\begin{align*}
        \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x
    & = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
    & = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 - \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x
      = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 - \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$
The same trivially holds if the upper limits are changed to $\pi/2$ as well ($x \mapsto \pi/2 -u$).
But I had problems proving the first equality. Does anyone have some quick hints?

Comment: consider evaluating $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} - \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos (2x)}{1 +\frac{1}{2}\sin(2 x)}\,\mathrm{d}x   $$

Comment: Are you not satisfied yet with the answers below?

Comment: Oh I am. I have a habit of waiting a few days, and it just so happened a flu struck. Been lying in bed for a few days or so

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Oh sorry, I didn't know that. Get well soon ᕙ( ^ₒ^ c)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova Thanks, the problem will be placed in here eventually ^^ http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/Integral%20Kokeboken.pdf

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Make sure cited my name, lol. *kidding BTW, it's a nice book. Is there the English version?

Comment: Someday ;)${}{}{}$

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Anyway, I'm interesting in knowing the first integral in the cover $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi x^2)}{\sinh(\pi x)}\,dx=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}$$How to prove it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61605/tough-integral-involving-sinx2-and-sinh2-x If you want further discussion ping me in chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the integral into two terms with limit $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x =\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x +\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
\end{align}
Using identity
\begin{align}
\int_a^{b} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^{b} f(a+b-x) \,\mathrm{d}x 
\end{align}
Also the facts that $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\sin x$, $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos x$, $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x\right)=-\sin x$, and $\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x\right)=-\cos x$, we get
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x &=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \sin x \cos x} \,\mathrm{d}x +\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{(-\sin x)^2}{1 + \sin x \cos x} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

Let
\begin{align}
I=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x =\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
2I&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x +\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2 + (\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x\\
I&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

Using $(2)$, we get
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{2 + 2\cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{2 + \sin (2x)} \,\mathrm{d}x\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad x\mapsto2x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2 + \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

A quick hint is noticing the symmetry. A rigorous proof is that $$\int\limits_a^b {\frac{{f(\cos x)}}{{g(\sin x\cos x)}}dx}  = \int\limits_a^b {\frac{{f\left( {\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - x} \right)} \right)}}{{g\left( {\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - x} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - x} \right)} \right)}}dx}  = \int\limits_{\frac{\pi }{2} - b}^{\frac{\pi }{2} - a} {\frac{{f\left( {\sin u} \right)}}{{g\left( {\cos u\sin u} \right)}}du} $$Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Agree, but then you need to split the limits to show the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the two integrals in question and get

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\cos{2 x}}{1+\frac12 \sin{2 x}} = \frac12 \int_0^{2 \pi} du \frac{\cos{u}}{1+\frac12 \sin{u}}$$

This may be shown to be equal to  the complex integral

$$-\frac{i}{4} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} \frac{z+z^{-1}}{1+\frac{1}{4 i} (z-z^{-1})}  = \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z} \frac{z^2+1}{z^2+i 4 z-1}$$

The poles of the integrand within the unit circle are at $z=0$ and $z=-(2-\sqrt{3}) i$; their respective residues are $-1$ and $1$.  By the residue theorem, therefore, the integral is zero and the two original integrals are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The integrands are both periodic with period $\pi$, so it suffices to verify the identity over any interval of length $\pi$, including $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Then, since both integrands are even functions, it suffices to check that the identity holds when integrating over $\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, that is, that
$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

But one can show this simply by substituting $x = \frac{\pi}{2} - u$ on either side.

Comment: Your answer was the first I got, andthe first one I used. However for later readers who also stumble uppon this integral I feel the answer given by Anastasiya is clearer.

Comment: The important thing is that you've learned something from posting here, which it seems you have.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\cos(\pi/2-x)^2}{1+\cos(\pi/2-x)\sin(\pi/2-x)} =
\frac{\sin(x)^2}{1+\sin(x)\cos(x)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

> $$I=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
>   $$J=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

---

Use $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^nf(a+b-x)dx$ and $\int_0^{2a}f(x)dx=\int_0^a f(x)dx+f(2a-x)dx$

---

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\cos (\pi-x))^2}{1 + \cos (\pi-x) \sin (\pi-x)} \,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 - \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\cos (\pi/2-x))^2}{1 - \cos (\pi/2-x) \sin (\pi/2-x)} \,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{(\cos (\pi/2-x))^2}{1 + \cos (\pi/2-x) \sin (\pi/2-x)} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 - \sin x \cos x} \,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 - \sin x \cos x} \,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{(\sin (\pi-x))^2}{1 - \cos (\pi-x) \sin(\pi-x)} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 - \sin x \cos x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

---

Hope you can now show that:
$$J=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\cos x)^2}{1 + \cos x \sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\cos (\pi/2-x))^2}{1 + \cos (\pi/2-x) \sin (\pi/2-x)} \,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1 + \sin x \cos x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$